# Will a Google Analytics tracking id send data from a different domain?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

We're using Google's Universal Analytics.  I've created a property with a website address of mywebsite.com and have therefore received the javascript snippet needed to embed in my page.  From what I understand this will begin capturing data from this top level domain and subdomains for example, heynow.mywebsite.com.  However, in my case it is possible that this snippet will be served in a page that may have a completely different domain like yourwebsite.com.  My expectation is I would not see this data in my Google Analytics views.  Am I right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about advertising and domain management than programming.

Comment: You will see this in your reports unless you create filters in your GA Accounts that includes/excludes specific hostnames (the domain name setting in your account is applied to a few interface settings like in-page analyses but has no effect on data collection). I cannot really decide if this is on-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.  Referrer spam use this technique to send you "false" events/pages/customDimensions hits to promoted their services.  To avoid this, make sure you :

1. exclude bots traffic (a setting from the view settings.)
2. include only traffic from your domain and sub-domain using a include filter (property level.)